# A meaningful sequence of numbers

Tags: number-sequence

The following sequence of numbers is related to a famous Conjecture.

17, 188, 94, 47, 518, 259, 37, 408, 204, 102, ?

Could you find the next number in the sequence?

Comment: Are you sure the 37 isn't a typo?

Comment: I am sure - I copied and also calculated it:)

Comment: sequence is known in OEIS:  https://oeis.org/A057614

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The next number is:

> $51$

The pattern:

> If the last term in the sequence so far is **prime**, multiply it by $11$ and add $1$, and if the last
>  term in the sequence so far is **composite**, divide it by its smallest prime factor. (equal to
>  $2$ except in one case, $259 \rightarrow 37$) The resulting number is the next term in the sequence.

The related conjecture is...

> ...the famous [Collatz Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture), except it involves always multiplying by $3$, and dividing by $2$.